# install local package with rpy2 - invalid package

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I'm trying to run a local r package and store the result it returned.

I've put the R package in the same directory as the python script. I've imported `importr` from `rpy2.robjects.packages` and had imported the `utils` package.

When I call the install.packages like this

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
utils = rpackages.importr('utils')
utils.install_packages('impactr_3.gz', repos = NULL, type="source")
```

The error produced was:

```
NameError: name 'NULL' is not defined.
```

How do I load this local R package with `rpy2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you define it, Python will not know any `NULL` (hence the error). If you want to use R's `NULL`, you can find it as `rpy2.robjects.NULL` or `rpy2.rinterface.NULL`.

Otherwise, the documentation for the R function you want to use indicates that paths can also be specified with the prefix `file://`:

```
utils.install_packages('file://impactr_1.0.1.tar.gz', type = "source")
```